# Are unbound descriptors possible?

Tags: python, properties, descriptor

(and if not, is there an approach that accomplishes a similar thing?)

For example, here's an example of a "bound" descriptor:

```
class VerboseDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, init):
        self.val = init

    def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
        print("[%s] Get is %s" % (obj, self.val))
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print("[%s] Set to %s" % (obj, val))
        self.val = val


class Holder(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Holder(%s)" % self.name

    val = VerboseDescriptor(2)


foo = Holder("foo")
_ = foo.val
foo.val = 4
```

Output (as expected):

```
[Holder(foo)] Get is 2
[Holder(foo)] Set to 4
```

Of course, something similar could be done with properties.

But, in the example, the `VerboseDescriptor` instance has to be an attribute of a class or instance (in this case, the class `Holder`).

In other words, the following **doesn't** work:

```
class VerboseDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, init):
        self.val = init

    def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
        print("[%s] Get is %s" % (obj, self.val))
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print("[%s] Set to %s" % (obj, val))
        self.val = val


val = VerboseDescriptor(2)

_ = val
val = 4
```

Neither `__get__` or `__set__` methods are called.  In the first line, `_` is just set to reference the same `VerboseDescriptor` instance as `val` and in the second, `val` is *changed* to reference 4.

So my question is, is there a way to build an object so that you can "catch" assignment to/from it, in the same way that descriptors allow you to catch assignment to/from class/instance attributes?

The question is more theoretical than practical.  I know there are very similar methods that involve classes (similar to my `Holder` class) that would suffice.  I'm just wondering whether this functionality is possible without `Holder`-type classes.

Reading:

- [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)
- [Implementing / Invoking Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors)

Comment: Normal variable assignments cannot be overridden in any way in Python, hence what you want to do is not possible.